# LP declared infeasible even though there exists a feasible solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $f, x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $m > n$, $X:=\{ x : Ax \geq b \}$, and $X$ is known to be non-empty. I have a "two-stage" optimization procedure as follows:

First, I solve the LP problem (let's name it as $\mathcal{P}_{1}$) and calculate $x_{i}^{*} = \max_{x \in X} x_{i}$, where $x_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ entry of $x$. Note that $i$ is a fixed value.

Then, using the $x_{i}^{*}$, I proceed to solve the following LP problem $\mathcal{P}_{2}$:

$\min_{y} f^{\top}y\\ \text{s.t.} \\ y \in X, \\ y_{i}=x_{i}^{*}.$

The issue is, I can find the optimal solution for $\mathcal{P}_{1}$, but sometimes $\mathcal{P}_{2}$ turns out to be infeasible. To my understanding, $\mathcal{P}_{2}$ must always be feasible given $\mathcal{P}_{1}$ is feasible (e.g., $y=x^{*}$ is a feasible solution for $\mathcal{P}_{2}$), but my solver (MOSEK/GAMS) sometimes struggle to find a feasible solution for $\mathcal{P}_{2}$. Usually $\mathcal{P}_{1}$ is solved within few seconds but for $\mathcal{P}_{2}$, the solver declares infeasibility after several minutes of computation. This is especially true when the feasible space $X$ is small.

What could be the reason?

Comment: It is a little hard to follow  your notation but from the general description and the comment "This is especially true when the feasible space X is small" I would think that $P_2$ is a borderline infeasible problem / has a degenerate feasible set and the solver struggles numerically because of that.

Comment: You might be better off dumping the problem to a file and contacting Mosek support with the details

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you for the comment. Yes, $\mathcal{P}_{2}$ it is a borderline feasible problem. Sometimes $X$ includes only a single vector. Given this condition, what could be a possible approach to resolve the issue? I also tried Knitro, and the Matlab's native LP solver. I experience the same issue with them too.

Comment: Hard piece of cake for interior-point solvers. You could try simplex, it is also available in Mosek. Or try to reformulate he problem yourself before calling the solver. There could also be some solver settings that could help but that is hard to say without seeing the data.